# How to unset a Qt attribute

Tags: qt, attributes, unset, setattribute

I am setting an attribute using `setAttribute( Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent );` Is there a way I can unset this attribute? Or is there a default attribute that I need to set to get it back to the way it was? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the second parameter,

`setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent , false)`

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute